# Kendo Sort not working

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

i have implemented a kendo grid as shown below , paging works without any issues but sort not work. Could you please help

CSHTML

```
<div class="panel">
<div id="CsHistory" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="float:none; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        @using PC.Cmgr.Claims.Domain.Models;
        @using PC.Cmgr.Claims.Domain.Common;
        @using PC.Cmgr.Models;
        @using System.Linq;
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CsAuditTrailViewModel>
            ()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto; height:auto; text-center;margin-right: 30px;margin-left: 30px; " })
            .Name("AllCsHistory")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.CsAuditTrailId).Title("CsAuditTrailId");                
            })
            .ToolBar(toolBar =>
            {
            })
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(false))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(o => o.CsAuditTrailId);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetCHistoryByClaimId", "Claims", new { ClaimId = Model.Claim.ClaimId }))
            .Events(events => { events.Sync("sync_handler"); }
            )
            )
        )

    </div>

</div>
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetCsHistoryByClaimId([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Guid ClaimId)
    {
        var CsHistory = await _CsHistoryProxy.GetCsHistoryByClaimId(ClaimId);
        var rawData = new ConcurrentBag<CsAuditTrailViewModel>();
        var gridData = new List<CsAuditTrailViewModel>();
        Parallel.ForEach(CsHistory, (x) =>
        {
            rawData.Add(
                new CsAuditTrailViewModel
                {
                    CsAuditTrailId = x.CsAuditTrailId,                      
                    NewData = x.NewData,
                    OldData = x.OldData,                       
                    UpdateDate = x.UpdateDate,
                    UserId = x.UserId                                        
                });
        });



        ViewData["total"] = rawData.Count();

        // Apply paging
        if (request.Page > 0)
        {             
            gridData = rawData.Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize).ToList();
        }

        gridData = gridData.Take(request.PageSize).ToList();


        var result = new DataSourceResult()
        {
            Data = gridData,
            Total = (int)ViewData["total"]
        };

        return Json(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wil have to customize it for your solution.
The sort-fields are in your DataSourceRequest, you can process them in your controller. See this example:

```
if (request.Sorts.Any())
    {
        foreach (SortDescriptor sortDescriptor in request.Sorts)
        {
            if (sortDescriptor.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                switch (sortDescriptor.Member)
                {
                    case "OrderID":
                        orders= orders.OrderBy(order => order.OrderID);
                        break;
                    case "ShipAddress":
                        orders= orders.OrderBy(order => order.ShipAddress);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (sortDescriptor.Member)
                {
                    case "OrderID":
                        orders= orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.OrderID);
                        break;
                    case "ShipAddress":
                        orders= orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.ShipAddress);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will have to do the sorting before the paging...

Taken from : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding

Comment: What is SortDescriptor here?

Comment: SortDescriptor is from Namespace Kendo.Mvc  (=> Kendo.Mvc.SortDescriptor) It contains the sorting as set in the grid (one or more in request.Sorts)

Answer (score 1):

From Telerik FAQs,

> For ajax binding scenarios the ToDataSourceResult extension method must be used to perform the data processing

So, you have to do it this way,

```
var result = new DataSourceResult()
{
    Data = gridData.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data,
    Total = (int)ViewData["total"]
};
```